# emacs prelude: how to bind evil toogle key to "C-q"

Tags: emacs

I am using emacs prelude and enable evil mode. Then in the file of /home/oracle/.emacs.d/personal/daniel.el I have the following line

```
(setq evil-toggle-key "C-q")
```

But emacs still use C-z as evil toggle-key.

Comment: You probably need `set-key` or `global-set-key`

Comment: I tried it, but it said definition of evil-toggle-key is void. And that error makes sense, since evil-toggle-key is not a function, but a variable

Comment: Use the help on your mode.